# Two tables of contents in a beamer presentation

Tags: beamer, table-of-contents

Is it possible to have two table of contents in beamer which contain the contents of two different sections, e.g. the main part and the appendix part. One table of content only includes sections from the main part, and the latter one which is shown after the main part only shows the appendix sections?

Answer (score 1):

The `\appendix` macro will automatically do this for you:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\tableofcontents
\end{frame}

\section{main section}
\begin{frame}
\end{frame} 
    
\appendix

\begin{frame}
\tableofcontents
\end{frame}

\section{appendix section}
\begin{frame}
\end{frame} 

\end{document}
```